# Zipping XML into GZIPOutputStream

Tags: java, xml, stax, jaxp

I am trying to use the StaX API to create some XML, save it in a FileOutputStream and put that stream inside a GZIPOutPutStream.

Clearly I am doing something wrong however because the following code outputs a corrupt file: hellow.xml.gz. I can open the zip file and see the xml file inside. However on extracting I get an error saying the file is broken.

The code works just file if I output to a text file rather than attempting to zip up the file with GZIPOutPutStream. How do I get the xml to write and compress into the gzip correctly?

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws XMLStreamException, IOException {

        FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(new File("/home/user/hellow.xml.gz"));
        GZIPOutputStream outputStreamZip = new GZIPOutputStream(outputStream);
        XMLOutputFactory factory = XMLOutputFactory.newInstance();

        XMLStreamWriter writer = factory.createXMLStreamWriter(outputStreamZip, "UTF-8");

        writer.writeStartElement("WOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOT");
        writer.writeStartElement("Lookup_Value_Record");
        writer.writeCharacters("Hello World");

        writer.writeEndElement();
        writer.writeEndElement();
        writer.writeEndDocument();

        writer.flush();
        writer.close();

    }
}
```

Comment: This code does not output a .txt file. I suggest you aren't running  the code you think you're running.

Comment: You must have been right EJP because when I run it now its outputting a corrupted gzip file rather than a text file. I updated the question to reflect this.

Answer (score 1):

The answer was very very simple. I just needed to close the Gzip output stream.

```
outputStreamZip.close();
```